# Does hunger necessarily mean that we should eat?

Tags: metabolism, nutrition, digestion, carbohydrates, blood-sugar

People feel hunger sooner after they eat food that consists mostly of carbohydrates. For example, if someone eats a good portion of rice then most likely they will be hungry after a couple of hours. But should they eat again in such a case or is it just deception because of blood sugar hikes?